# i need simple sql query

Tags: sql, database

here is the database table :

```
Stagiaire(numstagiaire,nom_stag,prenom_stag,adresse,email,#num_groupe)

Groupe(num_groupe,nom_groupe,#num_filiere)

Filière(num_filiere,nom_filiere)

Contrôle(num_controle,date_controle,#num_module)

Notation(#numstagiare ,# num_controle,note)

Module(num_module,nom_module,masse_horaire_prevue,masse_horaire_réalisé,#numformateur)

Formateur(numformateur,nomf,prenomf, num_filiere)
```

i need query to select all `stagiaire` columns who have `filiere.nom_filiere = "TDM"` and in `"A" or "B" Groupe.nom_groupe`

Comment: Write question clearly. add some table data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st.* FROM Stagiaire st 
INNER JOIN Groupe gr ON st.num_groupe = gr.num_groupe
INNER JOIN Filiere fi ON gr.num_filiere = fi.num_filiere
WHERE fi.nom_filiere = "TDM" AND (gr.nom_groupe = "A" OR gr.nom_groupe = "B");
```

It depends on SQL Database Server.

By the way. Be beware of naming tables. Some SQL Servers doesn't support some special characters (like Filière)